# How to count occurences of a word in a certain element in a text file?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is the code that i have so far and my problem is that it goes through every single word in the text file but instead i only want it to go through the last word of each line (the genre of the book: religion etc.)

```
import string 

    # Open the file in read mode 
    text = open("book_data_file.txt", "r") 

    # Create an empty dictionary
    d = dict()


    # Loop through each line of the file 
    for line in text: 
            # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
            line = line.strip() 

            # Convert the characters in line to 
            # lowercase to avoid case mismatch 
            line = line.lower() 

            # Remove the punctuation marks from the line 
            line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) 

            # Split the line into words 
            words = line.split(" ")

            

            # Iterate over each word in line 
            for word in words:
                    # Check if the word is already in dictionary 
                    if word in d: 
                            # Increment count of word by 1 
                            d[word] = d[word] + 1
                    else: 
                            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
                            d[word] = 1

    # Print the contents of dictionary 
    for key in list(d.keys()): 
            print(key, ":", d[key])
```

And this is a screenshot of the text file
[book text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlgxD.png)

My desired output is
religion: 4
science:3
fiction: 2
etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post text from .txt file don't put link containing screenshot. Can't you use pandas? 
since they all are separted by comma.

Comment: Nah sorry dude because im new to this site it doesnt give me permission to just post the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pandas`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=',')
words_count = df['GENRE'].value_counts()
```

**Edit:**

Just take the last word using indexing: `word = line.split(" ")[-1]`
Ignore 1st line because they are having headings and also if there is any new line then also skip. by using:

```
if idx==0 or len(line)==0:
     continue
```

**book.txt:**

```
a, b, c, d
a1, b1, c1, d1
a2, b2, c2, d2
a3, b3, c3, d1
a4, b4, c4, d1
a5, b5, c5, d3
```

---

```
import string 

# Open the file in read mode 
text = open("book.txt", "r")

# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()


# Loop through each line of the file 
for idx, line in enumerate(text): 

        # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
        line = line.strip()
        
        if idx==0 or len(line)==0:
            continue

        # Convert the characters in line to 
        # lowercase to avoid case mismatch 
        line = line.lower() 

        # Remove the punctuation marks from the line 
        line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) 

        # Split the line into words 
        word = line.split(" ")[-1]

        # Check if the word is already in dictionary 
        if word in d: 
                # Increment count of word by 1 
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
                # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
                d[word] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary 
for key in list(d.keys()): 
        print(key, ":", d[key])
```

---

```
d1 : 3
d2 : 1
d3 : 1
```

Comment: yeah thanks dude, do you mind telling me where i try this line of code. Im going to have to do some research on pandas:

Comment: you don't need to do looping. Just `import pandas` and use this code. It will create a table like structure. just access the 'GENRE' column and do value_counts() to give count of values inside that column.

Comment: im sorry im confused im not sure how to implement that feature in order to fix my problem

Comment: What feature? You can solve it by using 2 line of code using pandas. Did you try it?

Comment: Oh sorry thats my bad. ive encountered another problem, im really new to coding so im just using the python IDLE and it doesnt have the module panda

Comment: `pip install pandas`. SInce you are a beginner you should download anaconda will require 600mb. Then next step should be how to install package using pip and creating virtual env using conda.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation im going to try install anaconda now. Its fine if you cant find a solution this way but do you see how i could carry out the task without using the panda module just so i fully understand the use of dict and lists

Comment: I updated my answer. If it helps close the question by accepting it as an answer. Also always post some samples from your text file as text not as picture because it will be easier for us to provide the solution as we have to make sample data manually.

Comment: if idx==0 or len(line)==0 or (line.startswith('#')):
            continue

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use pandas, you're on the right way by using a `dict`.
There is actually a subclass of `dict` in the standard library that does exactly what you want: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```py
import string
from collections import Counter

def tokenize(line: str):
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
    line = line.strip() 

    # Convert the characters in line to 
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch 
    line = line.lower() 

    # Remove the punctuation marks from the line 
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) 

    # Split the line into words 
    words = line.split(" ")


def iter_tokens(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield from tokenize(line)


# Open the file in read mode
with open("book.txt", "r") as text:
    counts = Counter(iter_tokens(content))
```